# How can I rename a pathname for the default resources generated by Phoenix.Router?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a `UsersController` which I'm using for authentication not so much for viewing users profiles and what not, so I got

```
/users/new // GET
/users/new // POST
/users/login // GET
/users/login // POST
```

I want to rename this to

```
/auth/register
/auth/register
/auth/login
/auth/login
```

Is it possible to accomplish this right through the router?

Right now I have something like this:

```
resources "/users", UserController, only: [:create, :new]
```

Is there any way to do something like

```
resources "/auth", UserController, only: [create: "register", new: "register"]
```

or something like that. Any information would be great thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible right now using `resources` as the paths are all hardcoded in the route generators in `Phoenix.Router`: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/6350e7052548c939b572dbf6d5556c88bed4212d/lib/phoenix/router.ex#L208-L233

You'll have to create the routes manually:

```
get "/users/register", UserController, :new
post "/users/register", UserController, :create
```